# Python spacy lemmatization issue

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, lemmatization

While performing lemmatization using spacy i want all proper nouns to be considered as nouns. How do I customise this?

Tried :[(term.lemma_ for term in nlp("awards mvp awards") ]
Expected results: "award mvp award"
Observed results: "award mvp awards"
I understand that this is observed because mvp awards is considered as a proper noun.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please see the lemmatizer FAQ, which has an example of that. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/11685